# Load css style into body tag from body script in Angular application

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am trying to override the `style` property of the `body` tag with a `script` like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.onload = function() { 
        document.body.style.cssText = 'color: red' 
    }
</script>
```

The problem is, I'm embedding some code generated from an API Rest into an Angular application, where I have many constraints:

- I don't have premission to code into the Angular application itself
- Also I can't modify the `head` tag
- The `<div id='content'>` is the code I can embed into the Angular application

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body style=''>
        <app-root>
            <div id='content'>
                ...
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                    window.onload = function() { 
                        document.body.style.cssText = 'color: red' 
                    }
                </script>
                ...
                <p>some text</p>
            </div>
        </app-root>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then when I load the Angular application in the browser, the `<body style=''>` does not change.

I have tried a vanilla sample without Angular, and it's working as expected: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tj23r068/)

Since I have barely no experience in Angular, my question is: Does Angular have any constraint that prevents to modify any html tag outside its scope?

Comment: why did you set in styles.css ?

Comment: Angular overwrites everything in `<app-root>` tag during bootstraping, so inserting code within this tag is not good idea. Are you trying do modify index.html or another html file which is Angular Template file? Could you provide Fiddle with your real case?